# How to log a data-frame to an output file

Tags: python, pandas, logging

I'm starting to use logging to an output file but can't see how to log the head of a data-frame.  Is it possible?

I've tried debug (`logger.debug("snaptable", snap_date.head()`), where snap_table is a data-frame, but I can't see any output when I interrogate the output file.

Is there a type of logging that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`snap_date.head()` returns `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` object:

```
>>> type(snap_date.head())
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

You should convert it to str, because [logger.debug](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.debug) arguments (msg and *args) must be format string and string arguments. Try [pandas.DataFrame.to_string](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_string):

```
logger.debug("Snap_date:\n %s", snap_date.head().to_string())
```